# Get only the first 20 characters of XML node inner text

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have no problem populating a listbox with the inner text of a node list, but how can I change the code below to give me only the first 20 characters of the node's inner text (in case you are wondering, all the nodes have way more than 20 characters.

```
    For Each subjects As Xml.XmlNode In sbList
       subjectBox.Items.Add(subjects.InnerText)
    Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
For Each subjects As Xml.XmlNode In sbList
  subjectBox.Items.Add(subjects.InnerText.Substring(0,20))
Next
```

Comment: Ahh, substring --couldn't remember. THX

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use Left if you already had Microsoft.VisualBasic in your project

```
For Each subjects As Xml.XmlNode In sbList
  subjectBox.Items.Add(Left(subjects.InnerText,20))
Next
```